# Timezone offset not working for device?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, timezone, nsdate

I'm trying to get the timezone offset, but I am not getting the expected result. For example, in Cupertino, California I can easily get the correct timezone from Google's API with this:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=37.3086,-122.0891&timestamp=1436464494.938019

It returns this:

```
{
"dstOffset": 3600,
"rawOffset": -28800,
"status": "OK",
"timeZoneId": "America/Los_Angeles",
"timeZoneName": "Pacific Daylight Time"
}
```

The `rawOffset` is what I'm after. However, when I do this in the same device with the same location:

```
NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone().secondsFromGMT
```

It gives me `-14400` instead of `-28800` which is a huge difference. Am I missing something, how can I get the `rawOffset` locally from the device instead of calling Google's web service?

Comment: Check timezone name of NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone(). Does that look right?

Comment: Are you sure that time zone settings on your phone are correct?

Comment: `NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone().secondsFromGMT` returns the same `-14400` results :(

Comment: What is `NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone().description` ?

Comment: Oh it's returning my location, not the one in the simulator. In the simulator I have it set to Apple's location. Does timezone not work with the simulator?

Comment: For the simulator, it uses your computer's time setting. It is not tied to the location set in the simulator.

Comment: On real device time zone setting goes from Settings -> General -> Date & Time -> Time Zone. It can be set manually, not by actual GPS coordinates. There are no such settings on simulator. I think simulator takes mac's time zone settings. It can be the reason of differences.

Comment: "Debug -> Location" is for location services. I don't think that is has any influence on the *time zone*.

Comment: Ok you are all right, the timezone in code is retrieved from the mac computer not the simulator, which defeats Debug -> Location in that respect :(

Comment: You're also not considering that the system time zone is likely including a DST adjustment.  You can't just use the raw offset without considering if DST is in effect.  Better to use the time zone ID.